# How to mount a servlet filter in blaze server (http4s)

Tags: scala, http4s

I am a newbie in scala world and using http4s for developing the REST layer of my application. I am using blaze server for deploying/publishing the services. I need to mount a servlet filter or interceptor in the flow before it reaches my HttpService methods. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

http4s library has so called [middleware](http://http4s.org/v0.17/middleware/) functionality. Middleware functionality is a wrapper around your service.
For example, you have simple endpoint:

```
 val helloWorldService = HttpService {
  case GET -> Root / "hello" / name =>
    Ok(s"Hello, $name.")
}
```

To apply middleware you may do the following:

```
     val service: HttpService = middleware(authedService)

      val authedService: AuthedService[User] =
        AuthedService {
          case GET -> Root / "welcome" as user => Ok(s"Welcome, ${user.name}")
        }
      val middleware = AuthMiddleware(authUser)
```

and your just need to implement your `authUser` :

```
val authUser: Service[Request, User] = ???
```

You may want to check out the org.http4s.server.middleware package for already existent middleware.